# Injecting code into AngularJS file using grunt task

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, task

I'm trying to inject code into my app.js file that will be triggered when I run my "grunt serve" task. It's just two lines of javascript that needs to be present when running the app in my local environment, but I'm not sure how to get the code in. I've tried this plug to no avail: https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-inject. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) you can conditionnaly add part of code in a html/js/css/anything...

Example from doc :

A `script.tpl.js` file will get processed as a `script.js` with the `someDebuggingCall()` line only if you set the `DEBUG` var in your GruntFile :

```
// @ifdef DEBUG
someDebuggingCall()
// @endif
someCode()
```

with the gruntFile.js containing :

```
preprocess : {
  options: {
    context : {
      DEBUG: true
    }
  },
  js : {
    src : 'script.tpl.js',
    dest : 'script.js'
  }
}
```

See doc for more infos.